# Find this Mate in 1

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

[image]

This position was from one of my online games on Chess.com. I had the white pieces and was very close to victory. However, I couldn't find the mate in 1 as stockfish did.

Where on earth was the mate in 1?

Comment: This puzzle is a *retrograde* puzzle i.e. you must deduce what happened before to reach the current position. Based on the position, you are supposed to deduce that black could not have made any possible move to get to this situation, so it *cannot* be white's move. Now, no matter what move black makes, it is M1, and these moves are not hard to find on your own. [Link to video of this exact puzzle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhbIuz6rnOA).

Comment: The flavor story is a bit too misleading for a puzzle I think.

Comment: This famous problem was composed by Walter Freiherr von Holzhausen in 1901 (Akademisches Monatsheft für Schach)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume

> It's Black's move

Then

> Black has 3 legal moves: 1... Rxa7 allows 2. Rc8# and 1... Kxa7 allows the pretty 2. b8(N)# and 1... Kxc7 leads to 2. bxa8(N)#

Comment: No need to assume. It can be deduced (assuming the position resulted from natural and legal play, which is still an assumption, but a better one IMO).

Comment: There is a convention in the WFCC Codex for Chess Composition, that if the usual player can't possibly just have moved (so called retro-stalemate) then it's the other guy to move. (Other joke possibilities exist too: e.g. rotate the board, make it Black mating White, etc.) Now does White lose a move or does Black gain a move? Again by the convention, for adversarial problems, the bad guys get an extra move.

Comment: at the end white wins right?

Comment: @alper yes. # is shorthand for checkmate